# Firestore array to swift struct mapping

Tags: swift, struct, google-cloud-firestore, nsarray

I've been going round in circles trying to figure out how to map a firebase document to a swift struct. I've got it working well, except I've now added an array within my firebase database and am having zero luck trying to map it to my struct.

Here is my struct:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct subData {

    var userID: String
    var topScore: Int
    var extended: Contents

    init(Doc: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.userID = Doc.get("userID") as? String ?? "nil"
        self.topScore = Doc.get("topScore") as? Int ?? 0
        self.extended = Contents(data: Doc.get("extendedArray") as! [String: Any])!

    }
}

struct Contents {
    var ID00: Int
    var ID01: Int
    var ID02: Int
    var ID03: Int

    init?(data: [String: Any]) {

        guard let ID00 = data["ID00"] as? Int,
            let ID01 = data["ID01"] as? Int,
            let ID02 = data["ID02"] as? Int,
            let ID03 = data["ID03"] as? Int else {
                return nil
        }

        self.ID00 = ID00
        self.ID01 = ID01
        self.ID02 = ID02
        self.ID03 = ID03
    }
}
```

Here is my Firestore Database structure:

[image]

I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1ccc3b660) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1ccc3c628).
```

I know, I know...the error message is quite clear in what I'm doing wrong - but I've gone round in circles so many times I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction....

Thanks.

Comment: If you do know that you added an **array** why do you cast the object to **dictionary**? The error message is indeed very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `extendedArray`

```
self.extended = Contents(data: Doc.get("extendedArray") as! [String: Any])!
```

Is an array not a dictionary , so it should be

```
Doc.get("extendedArray") as! [[String: Any]]
```

Use https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase for easy decoding

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've tried your suggestion:

`self.extended = Doc.get("extendedArray") as! [[String: Any]]`

but I get the following error:
`Cannot assign value of type '[[String : Any]]' to type 'Contents'`

I clearly don't understand structs and dictionaries as much as I should - I need to go and read up on what I'm doing wrong

Comment: OK - I've done some reading and come to the following conclusion, please shout at me if it's wrong! I've modified my struct as follows:

`var extended : Array<Any>`

and deleted `struct Contents` as it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

I followed your advice above and did the following:

`self.extended =  Doc.get("extendedArray") as! [[String: Any]]`

This seems to have worked and maps the Firestore array contents to .extended allowing me to access as needed.

Comment: it's `var extended :[[String:Any]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Sh_Khan, much appreciated.

Am I right in thinking `struct Contents` is not used given we don't assign `extended` property to type `Contents`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the model, the below model is right solution,

```
struct subData {

    var userID: String
    var topScore: Int
    var extended:[[String:Any]]

    init(Doc: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.userID = Doc.get("userID") as? String ?? "nil"
        self.topScore = Doc.get("topScore") as? Int ?? 0
        self.extended = Doc.get("extendedArray") as! [[String: Any]]

    }
}
```

Also Note that if the `var extended: NSDictionary?` is of kind Dictionary should use `self.extended = Doc.get("extendedArray") as? NSDictionary` instead like wise depends on array or dictionary or any other kind.